# Old book about three girls unlocking their (fairy?) powers thanks to a magical stone

Tags: story-identification, books, fairy

I read the book 5 years ago and I forgot the name.

It has a light pink cover with a short-hair fairy on it. First few pages are comics and then words.

I can barely remember the content but it's about three ordinary girls who receive some magical stone, then suddenly they got caught and trapped by some water bubbles (stuff like that) and ready to transport somewhere unknown. Their power is being triggered by the stone.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 7):

It could be the [*W.I.T.C.H.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W.I.T.C.H.) series (2004 onwards), at least the novels.

**Arguments in favor:**

- Fairy with short hair.
- Pink cover - take a look at the first one's cover, in various languages. Granted, the French one is a bit more pinkish, but the English one fits light pink too.

[image: English cover]

[image: French cover]

- The novels start with some comics and then actual words, along with some comic inserts along the way (it's even adverted on the English cover).
- The pink stone shooting pink light (yeah, that's a lot of pink) is the Heart of Kandrakar universe, granting the five girls powers over the elements.

Which leads me to **arguments against:**

- Five girls and not three. Although it's actually a group of three girls joined by the two new girls at school early in the series.
- There wasn't bubble stuff that early in the series. I read like three novels, but all of the comics, and in the ~200 issues I'm pretty sure there was at least one bubble scene. But that early, I can't think of one.
- The "element control" powers are a big deal, one would probably remember them.

Comment: If you have two answers, split them into two answers. That way, people can vote on them separately. :)

Comment: Okay! I'm new here, I'll do that right away :)

Answer (score 2):

Another answer could be the [*Rainbow Magic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Magic) series (2003 onwards). No particular book, though.

From Wikipedia:

> The series follows the lives of Kirsty Tate and Rachel Walker and their magical adventures with their fairy friends.

**Arguments in favor:**

- Take a look at [what Google Images return](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=rainbow%20magic). There's around 150 books of this, [lots of them with pink cover](https://www.google.com/search?q=rainbow%20magic&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=ic:specific,isc:pink) and short hair (depends of what you consider short, though). For instance:

[image: Rainbow Magic pink covers]

- This extract from the book [*Sky the blue fairy*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=BMTcfLQePvMC&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=%22rainbow%20magic%22%20water%20bubble&f=false)(the cover is yellow, granted, but from what I've seen, one could easily mistake two of those books). There's a bubble

> Sky's bubble was floating just below the surface.

and a stone which seems magical

> It was still warm from the magic stone.

- There are drawings inside the book. Taken from Google Books above:

[image: Rainbow Magic inside art]

**Arguments against :**

- Two girls, not three.
- The bubble thingy is not quite what you said.
- Not having read the books, I honestly have no idea how the two girls came across the fairies.